# PowerShell - Cannot pass values of textboxes from an Add_Click to another

Tags: powershell, function, parameter-passing, variable-assignment, windows-forms-designer

I'm workin on a script with a GUI on powershell, but I have the following problem:

```
 $buttonactivedirectory.Add_Click({ 
           #create a label and textbox ou
            $OU= label OU 20 40 OU
            $OUtextbox= label 500 30 250 40 OUtextbox

           #create a label and textbox domain
            $domain=  label DOMAIN 20 100 domain
            $domaintextbox= textbox 500 30 250 100 domaintextbox

           #create a label and textbox path
            $path=  label "PATH TXT" 20 160 path
            $pathtextbox= textbox 500 30 250 160 pathtextbox
          
          #create a button to create an user
            $buttoncreateuser = button 500 30 250 230 "CREATE USER"
         
          #I get the values of the textbox above
            $ou_variable = $($OUtextbox.text)
            $domain_variable = $($domaintextbox.text)
            $pathtextbox_variable = $($pathtextbox.text)

            #when I press "CREATE USER button"

  $buttoncreateuser.Add_Click({
                          
          
          write-host $OU_variable 
         write-host $domain_variable           
         write-host $pathtextbox_variable
#here's the problem > empty values!! I want the values of textboxes above

})
})
```

As you can see on the script above, I'm trying to pass the values of the textboxes from an Add_Click to another which is contained into the first one.

I've tried everything, also with GLOBAL variables but anything work, I always have empty values.

I've tried to declare variables as GLOBAL and moving this

```
 $ou_variable = $($OUtextbox.text)
            $domain_variable = $($domaintextbox.text)
            $pathtextbox_variable = $($pathtextbox.text)
```

into

```
$buttoncreateuser.Add_Click({
```

Please help me!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: In short: Event handlers run in a _child scope_, so in order to create or update a variable in the script's scope, you must use `$script:variable = ...`, otherwise you'll implicitly create a _block-local_ variable. See the linked duplicate for details.